# How to find records based on given latitude and longitude with given distance in PostgreSQL

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql

I am using this formula.

```
SELECT id, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(14.685327) ) * cos( radians( latitude ) ) 
    * cos( radians( longitude ) - radians(80.054889) ) + sin( radians(14.685327) ) * sin(radians(latitude)) ) ) AS distance 
FROM kr_user
HAVING distance < 50
ORDER BY distance
```

But I got error the following error:

```
ERROR: function radians(character varying) does not exist
LINE 1: ..., ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(14.685327) ) * cos( radians( l...
                                       ^
HINT: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

How to solve this. Or any other suggestion for this. I am using laravel platform for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess your latitude and longitude columns are of type varchar and not of type numeric (as 14.685327 is).

So, try :

```
SELECT id, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(14.685327) ) * cos( radians( latitude::numeric ) ) 
    * cos( radians( longitude::numeric ) - radians(80.054889) ) + sin( radians(14.685327) ) * sin(radians(latitude::numeric)) ) ) AS distance 
FROM kr_user
HAVING distance < 50
ORDER BY distance
```

Now as you point out in the comments, you can not filter on a calculated column, personally I would use a lateral join to solve this issue :

```
SELECT id, t.distance
FROM kr_user
INNER JOIN LATERAL (
  SELECT 3959 * acos(
    cos( radians(14.685327) ) *
    cos( radians( latitude::numeric ) ) *
    cos( radians( longitude::numeric ) - radians(80.054889) ) +
    sin( radians(14.685327) ) *
    sin(radians(latitude::numeric))
  ) AS distance
  WHERE latitude IS NOT NULL AND longitude IS NOT NULL
) t ON TRUE
WHERE t.distance < 50
ORDER BY t.distance
```

Comment: Now error given column distance does not exist in having clause.

Comment: I do not have distance column in table. I have to find dynamic distance.

Comment: Now new error: invalid input syntax for type numeric: "NULL" CONTEXT: parallel worker

Comment: What does `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM kr_user WHERE latitude IS NULL OR longitude IS NULL` return?

Comment: It returns count 430765

Comment: Can U please give solution?

Comment: New error:  invalid input syntax for type numeric: "NULL"

Comment: Why it is coming?

Comment: You have NULL values in your data, which prevents the conversion from executing properly. I updated the query again according to the new error.

Comment: Sorry new error: syntax error at or near "WHERE" WHERE latitude IS NOT NULL AND longitude IS NOT NULL

Comment: Indeed, my bad. Let my fix this.

Comment: Hi Fabian. Sorry to say. But I am stuck in above query from yesterday. Can U please help?

Comment: Doesn't the last version work? I updated just after my last comment